# Socket chat system - broadcasting them to all clients

Tags: c++, chat, winsock

Communication between a server and a clients works, but the server don't forward the client messages to the other connected client's, but only to the sender.

i want the server react to incoming messages by broadcasting them to all clients like a chat system, but keep my command system without sharring it with all clients, but with with sender.

down below is the sources:

**server**

```
    /*server*/
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <process.h>

// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib, Mswsock.lib, and Advapi32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")


#define PORT "3490"

#define SERVER "localhost"


#include <time.h>

WSADATA wsa;

SOCKET s , new_socket;

struct sockaddr_in server , client;

int c;

char *message;

std::string line;



DWORD WINAPI ProcessClient (LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    SOCKET AcceptSocket = (SOCKET) lpParameter;

    // Send and receive data.
    int bytesSent;

    int bytesRecv = SOCKET_ERROR;

    char sendbuf[2000]="";
     char sendbuf2[2000]="";

    char recvbuf[2000]="";

    char timebuf[128];

    sprintf(sendbuf, "Hello, it's a test server at %s:%d (commands: 1, 2, exit)\n", SERVER, PORT);

    bytesSent = send( AcceptSocket, sendbuf, strlen(sendbuf), 0);

    if (bytesSent == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf( "Error at send hello: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        goto fin;
    }

    while (1)
    {
        _strtime( timebuf );
        ZeroMemory (recvbuf, sizeof(recvbuf));

        bytesRecv = recv( AcceptSocket, recvbuf, 32, 0);

        printf( "%s Client said: %s\n", timebuf, recvbuf);



        sprintf(sendbuf, "%s Client said: %s\n", timebuf, recvbuf);
        bytesSent = send( AcceptSocket, sendbuf, strlen(sendbuf), 0);


        if (strcmp(recvbuf, "1") == 0)
        {
            sprintf(sendbuf, "You typed ONE\n");
            //printf("Sent '%s'\n", sendbuf);
            bytesSent = send( AcceptSocket, sendbuf, strlen(sendbuf), 0);

            if (bytesSent == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                printf( "Error at send: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
                goto fin;
            }
        }
        else if (strcmp(recvbuf, "2") == 0)
        {
            sprintf(sendbuf, "You typed TWO\n");
            //printf("Sent '%s'\n", sendbuf);
            bytesSent = send( AcceptSocket, sendbuf, strlen(sendbuf), 0);

            if (bytesSent == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                printf( "Error at send: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
                goto fin;
            }
        }
        else if (strcmp(recvbuf, "exit") == 0)
        {
            printf( "Client has logged out\n", WSAGetLastError());
            goto fin;
        }
        else
        {
           // sprintf(sendbuf, "unknown command\n");
            //printf("Sent '%s'\n", sendbuf);
           //  bytesSent = send( AcceptSocket, sendbuf, strlen(sendbuf), 0);

            if (bytesSent == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
               // printf( "Error at send: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
                goto fin;
            }
        }
    }

fin:
    printf("Client processed\n");

    closesocket(AcceptSocket);
    return 0;
}




int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{

    std::cout << ("\nInitialising Winsock...");

    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
    {
        std::cout << ("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Initialised.\n");

    //Create a socket
    if((s = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cout << ("Could not create socket : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
    }

    std::cout << ("Socket created.\n");

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons( 3490 );

    //Bind
    if( bind(s ,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << ("Bind failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    puts("Bind done");



    //Listen to incoming connections
    listen(s , 3);



    //Accept and incoming connection
    std::cout << ("Waiting for incoming connections...");

    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    while(true){



  while((new_socket = accept(s , (struct sockaddr *)&client, &c)) != INVALID_SOCKET) {
        // Create a new thread for the accepted client (also pass the accepted client socket).
       printf( "Client Connected.\n");

        DWORD dwThreadId;
        CreateThread (NULL, 0, ProcessClient, (LPVOID) new_socket, 0, &dwThreadId);
    }





       }

    if (new_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cout << ("accept failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

**client**

```
    /*client*/
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")

#include <iostream>
#include <process.h>
#include <string>
#include <winsock2.h>



SOCKET Socket;

#define SERVER "localhost"

int PORT = 3490;

std::string line;


bool chat = false;



class Buffer
{

public:
    int ID;
    char Message[256];
}sbuffer;



int ClientThread()
{


 char buffer[2000]= "";

    for(;; Sleep(10))
    {
        if(recv(Socket, buffer, sizeof(sbuffer), NULL)!=SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            strncpy(sbuffer.Message, buffer, sizeof(sbuffer.Message));

            std::cout << "<Client:" << sbuffer.ID << ":> " << sbuffer.Message <<std::endl;

            ZeroMemory (buffer, sizeof(buffer));

        } 
    }

    return 0;
}


int main(void)
{
    WSADATA WsaDat;
    if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&WsaDat)!=0)
    {
        std::cout<<"Winsock error - Winsock initialization failed\r\n";
        WSACleanup();
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }

    // Create our socket

     Socket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(Socket==INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cout<<"Winsock error - Socket creation Failed!\r\n";
        WSACleanup();
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }

    // Resolve IP address for hostname
    struct hostent *host;
    if((host=gethostbyname(SERVER))==NULL)
    {
        std::cout<<"Failed to resolve hostname.\r\n";
        WSACleanup();
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }

    // Setup our socket address structure
    SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
    SockAddr.sin_port=htons(PORT);
    SockAddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr=*((unsigned long*)host->h_addr);

    // Attempt to connect to server
    if(connect(Socket,(SOCKADDR*)(&SockAddr),sizeof(SockAddr))!=0)
    {
        std::cout<<"Failed to establish connection with server\r\n";
        WSACleanup();
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }

    // If iMode!=0, non-blocking mode is enabled.
    u_long iMode=1;
    ioctlsocket(Socket,FIONBIO,&iMode);

    // Main loop
    for(;;)
    {


        // Display message from server
        char buffer[1000];
        memset(buffer,0,999);
        int inDataLength=recv(Socket,buffer,1000,0);
        std::cout<<buffer;



     CreateThread(NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) ClientThread, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    for(;; Sleep(10))
    {
        std::string buffer;
        std::getline(std::cin, buffer);


        if (send(Socket, buffer.c_str(), buffer.length(), NULL) < 1){



         }
    }





        int nError=WSAGetLastError();

        if(nError!=WSAEWOULDBLOCK&&nError!=0)
        {
            std::cout<<"Winsock error code: "<<nError<<"\r\n";
            std::cout<<"Server disconnected!\r\n";
            // Shutdown our socket
            shutdown(Socket,SD_SEND);

            // Close our socket entirely
            closesocket(Socket);

            break;
        }


        Sleep(1000);
    }

    WSACleanup();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Please help me fix it, i'm new into socket's. Show me how to do as i'm going understand better with code and it will also be usefull to others who might need it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the server to communicate with multiple clients, then you need some kind of collection of all the connected clients. Then it's easy to send to all connections, or send to all connection but the originating connection.

How to do it will differ *vastly* between C and C++, but for C++ look into structures and [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

---

In pseudo-code it would be something like this:

```
while (run_server)
{
    poll_all_connections();

    if (have_new_connection())
    {
        accept_new_connection();
        add_connection_in_collection();
    }
    else
    {
        for (connection in all_connections())
        {
            if (have_input(connection))
            {
                input = read_from_connection(connection);

                for (send_to in all_connections())
                    write_to_connection(connection, input)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you implement the above pseudo-code, then input from any connection will be sent to all connections.

Don't forget to remove a connection from the collection if the connection is broken (error or disconnect.)

Comment: The C++ way would be nice!! can you by any chance if you don't mind change the source to work as you said, please?

Comment: @SarahLarsen I've added some pseudo-code to show one way of handling it.

Comment: That what im searching for! i'm so happy that someone udnerstand me! ;* - but i'm having hard to understand the pseudo example, can you please... if you don't mind implant it inside the server i have posted so i can see and learn how it right done`?

Comment: @SarahLarsen There are _many_ chat-server tutorials if you just search a little, containing complete code examples.

Comment: I'm finding your way much more better, but i don't know how to implant that inside the server, it would mean the world to me if you could do that... i'm going accept your answer right away... please

Answer (score 1):

You have to maintain a list of all the client socket connections then send the data to each client one by one.

or you can use threading to implement this as follows :-

```
 Server-thread()
 {
   while(true)
    {
       /// Accept Connection in ClientSocket. 

       HandleClient-Thread(ClientSocket)  ; // launch a thread for each client .
     }

  } 

  HandleClient-Thread(ClientSocket)
   {
     // handle this client here 

   }
```

Comment: Can you please show me step by step or implant it inside the server`? that would be very helpfull and much better to understand :)

Comment: @you are saying to do your home work . just maintain an array of all incoming connection and then from a loop send data to all these one by one @ Joachim Pileborg already shown you .

Comment: I'm just asking polite if you don't mind to show me how so i can understand it and it going help anyone in fture... there is no  home work with this... i jsut don't know how to do that

Comment: I have edited my answer to give you a new idea to implement this .